# Nice answer badge

Tags: support, answers, badges

I was checking the "Badges" list in Drupal Answers and I found there is a "Nice Answer" badge for answers with a score of 10 or more.

The meaning of *score* is not clear. When someone up-votes an answer, then 10 points will be given to the user who wrote the answer.

Why didn't I get this badge for any of my answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *"score of 10 or more"* refers to the difference between the number of up-votes a post received, and the number of down-votes that post received; if a post got 5 up-votes and 2 down-votes, its score is 3 (5 - 2).

Currently your [highest-voted answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90270/where-does-drupal-save-the-trim-length-for-the-body-field/90275#90275) has 7 up-votes and no down-votes, so you're not far off getting the badge for that one.

Comment: Thanks for your details information.

Comment: I edited the answer, since it was not correct. A post with 5 up-votes and 2 down-votes has a score of 3, not 5.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks.